# Verificar se o conteúdo já existe no arquivo de texto

Tags: python, loop, for

Gostaria de saber como faço para verificar um arquivo TXT e caso tenha uma linha igual ele não adicionar novamente o conteúdo, caso contrário ele adicione.
Tentei fazer assim:

Tokens é um array com diversas strings, como por exemplo:

```
['Nzc3NzA2MTc2MzA4NzA3Mzc5.X7HVkg.v85rDccvWP-HJJxD_SMonOu', 'Nzc3NzA3ODI2Njg0MjMxNzEy.X7HXBw.CvxmjqeS8sW9Rx1sEy2ESLZ']
```

Gostaria de verificar esse array, e em cada item da lista ele verificar se já tem esse token no bloco de notas, e se não tiver ele adiciona, se ja tiver, nao precisa fazer nada além de printar que ja existe:

```
for i in range(0, len(tokens)): 
        print(str(tokens[i]))
        with open('tokens.txt', "rt") as f:
            datafile = f.readlines()
            for line in datafile:
                if str(tokens[i]) in line:
                    print("Já possue esse token")
                else:
                    with open('tokens.txt', "w") as f:
                        f.write(str(tokens[i]) + '\n')
                        message = str(tokens[i])
```

Porém não está funcionando, a variável "message" sempre recebe o token que já foi escrito no .TXT, o que devo fazer?

Comment: O que é essa variável `tokens`? Pode editar sua pergunta adicionando essa informação?

Comment: É para verificar cada string do array em cada linha, e se a string não estiver presente em nenhuma linha do .txt, a string deve ser escrita no final do arquivo certo?

Answer (score 1):

Tokens de exemplo:

```
tokens = [
    'Nzc3NzA2MTc2MzA4NzA3Mzc5.X7HVkg.v85rDccvWP-HJJxD_SMonOu', 
    'Nzc3NzA3ODI2Njg0MjMxNzEy.X7HXBw.CvxmjqeS8sW9Rx1sEy2ESLZ',
    'Nzc3NzA3ODI2Njg0MjMxNzEy.X7HXBw.CvxmjqeS8sW9Rx1sEy2ESLj',
    'Nzc3NzA3ODI2Njg0MjMxNzEy.X7HXBw.CvxmjqeS8sW9Rx1sEy2ESpl'
]
```

Abertura do arquivo no modo leitura

```
with open('./tokens.txt','r') as reader:
    tokens_reader = reader.readlines()
```

Removendo o \n(quebra de linha)

```
tokens_reader = [item.replace('\n','') for item in tokens_reader]
```

Abrindo o arquivo em modo escrita:

```
with open('./tokens.txt','a') as writer:
    writer.write('\n')
    writer.write('\n'.join(set.difference(set(tokens), set(tokens_reader))))
```

Note que esta linha é que faz o trabalho para verificar se existe conteúdo igual e grava no arquivo caso não exista

```
writer.write('\n'.join(set.difference(set(tokens), set(tokens_reader))))
```

Comparamos os tokens do script com os tokens do arquivo e retornamos essa diferença

set.difference:

> A diferença entre os dois conjuntos em Python é igual à diferença
> entre o número de elementos em dois conjuntos. A função difference()
> retorna um conjunto que é a diferença entre dois conjuntos.

---

Código inteiro:

```
with open('./tokens.txt','r') as reader:
    tokens_reader = reader.readlines()

tokens_reader = [item.replace('\n','') for item in tokens_reader]

with open('./tokens.txt','a') as writer:
    writer.write('\n')
    writer.write('\n'.join(set.difference(set(tokens), set(tokens_reader))))
```